# What can be done to seat post too long/saddle too high?

Tags: repair, saddle, adjustment

Recently a mountain bike --someone's hand-me-down--, came in my way. Size wise it might be slightly big for my ideal but within the range of manageable, I accessed. After trying a few times, however, it became clear that its seat post becoming too long and saddle too high with the way it was. I broke the parts apart and the only way I could make do with this seemed  not to use this post or any post at all, crazy it may sound, but it should work out only if the saddle cushion part immediately placed on the seating area. (Somehow the depth that the post can slide down is limited to half of the post length due to its structure: a "coil type' object obstructing and blocking the post. I'm a girl of 5 foot 2. Although the bike is a mountain type, I am not planning to use this for adventurous rides in mountains or slopes but for small scaled travel nearby with no bumps and/or environments as parks, etc. I am an experienced cyclist but also a city dweller, who would be cautious due to frequent casualties observed in the area where I am currently located: urban.

Comment: I think the frame is way too long for you, unless you have extremely short legs. On most frames the seatpost will stick at least 10cm out of the frame. Or maybe you are trying to lower the saddle much more than is actually necessary? As a rule of thumb your legs should be fully extended if you put your heels on the pedals in the 6 o'clock position.

Comment: For suspension bikes I've a couple of times had to saw off the end of a replacement seatpost to get it to fit.

Comment: I read a lot of comments where people are guessing what your seat post problem is. Would you be so kind to take a photo of the seat post and the bike to include it here?

Comment: If you need the seat this low, the bike is almost certainly too large, possibly dangerously large. You need to be able to put your feet on the ground in a sudden stop without injuring your groin on the top tube. If you can't, even the "small scale" travel that you describe can produce hazards. A sudden stop to avoid a dog, squirrel, car, or whatever could hurt you pretty badly.

Comment: Long seatposts are relatively hard to come by.  Instead of cutting it, check with a bike cooperative in your area, who may want to swap.   As a tall rider, long parts are worth keeping for their rarity.

Answer (score 6):

I think what you are saying is that you need to drop the seat post all the way down into the frame, so the saddle is as close to the frame as possible. You need a seat post to connect the saddle and frame. You can't attach the saddle directly to the frame.

If the post cannot be slid all the way into the frame due to an obstruction it can be cut down to shorten it. As long as the minumum length is inserted into the frame you will be structurally safe. You can buy a shorter post of course.

However, if you need to drop the saddle all the way to the frame the bike is likely too large for you and possibly dangerous, as you will have no standover clearance.

Comment: To me it sounds like op has full suspension frame and the seat post can't be fully inserted

Comment: A shorter/shortened post seems to be the only option. As long as the minimum insertion is OK.

Comment: *it can be cut down to shorten it*  It's probably a better idea to buy a shorter seat post.  Someone not familiar with how a seatpost works probably shouldn't be cutting one shorter.

Comment: Maybe OP has a suspension seatpost? She says the post can only be slid down half its length due to its structure. If that's the case, cutting won't help.

Answer (score 3):

Feel free to cut the seat post, but remember to keep a few inches in the frame.

Comment: You're totally right, but this is already covered by existing answers.  Instead of doubling up, use the Upvote button for existing answers which you think are most helpful.

Comment: not allowed to, I don't have enough reputation points.

Comment: Almost there - only 50 points required to comment everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten a seatpost with a pipe-cutter. This assumes that the seatpost has a uniform cross-section over its length, and isn't thinned out or narrowed above the expected clamping area.